# Online service to search in text files

Tags: web-services, cloud-service, text-search

I'm looking for an online service allowing me to search through 100k text files. Preferably with an easy way to upload/add these files (upload JSON or CSV file with URLs to text files).

Comment: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com).

Comment: Windows explorer will do that... why an online service?

Comment: @NeMo Because I want multiple people to be able to search the same files.

Comment: If they're on the same network they can access the networked drive. If not, set up a VPN.